# HTML/PHP form doesn't insert data to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP, and I have been trying to make a small Homework Organiser Application.

The idea is that you can input a Subject and Description and it will be added to a MySQL Database (that's it for now).

I have created a html form:

```
<form action="insert.php">
        <label for="subj">Subject:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="subj">
        <br>
        <label for="desc">Description:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="desc">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

and some php code:

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($subject);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);

$dbhost = ''; //These are filled in actually
$dbuser = ''; //These are filled in actually
$dbpass = ''; //These are filled in actually
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO organiser '.
    '(subject,description) '.
    'VALUES ('$subject', '$description')';

mysql_select_db(''); //These are filled in actually
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The problem is that the input from the Subject and Description boxes on the HTML form don't go into the MySQL Database.

However, If I set

```
'VALUES ('$subject', '$description')';
```

to

```
'VALUES ("test", "test")';
```

it works.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You're missing `method="post"` in your form element. Aside from that, you should be doing some validation server side before using the data, and you shouldn't be using `mysql_` as it's deprecated now.

Comment: For good measure: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you are using single quotes in your `$sql` declaration,

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO organiser '.'(subject,description) '.'VALUES ('$subject', '$description')';
```

When you use single quotes you are telling PHP that you would like everything within the quotes to be taken literally.

```
$age = 20; 
$myAge = 'I am $age years';
echo $myAge;
```

This would echo `I am $age years` since you used single quotes.

However, if you used double quotes instead,

```
$age = 20; 
$myAge = "I am $age years";
echo $myAge;
```

The output would be,

```
I am 20 years
```

Thus, your $sql statement should be (I write it on one line instead),

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO organiser (subject,description) VALUES ('$subject', '$description')";
       ^                                                                               ^
```

If you echo your $sql it would become something along the lines of,

```
INSERT INTO organiser (subject,description) VALUES ('Your subject', 'Your description')
```

Your use of single quotes within your SQL-statement is correct, you can read more about the subject here: [When to use single quotes, double quotes and backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer already given in regards to missing dots for the concatenate:

Form method **defaults to a GET** method, if the method is omitted from the form tag.

You are using `<form action="insert.php">` which is equivalent to doing
`<form action="insert.php" method = "get">` which is **not** what you want *nor* required.

Change it to

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

since you are using POST variables.

That is the **contributing** reason why `'VALUES ("test", "test")';` works and not the other way, since both of these variables `$subject` - `$description`, are based on your POST variables:

```
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
```

You can either do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO organiser (subject,description) VALUES ('$subject', '$description')";
```

as stated in a comment.

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO organiser (subject,description) VALUES ('".$subject."', '".$description."')";
```

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which would have signaled errors found in your code.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

---

Yet, your method is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Use a `mysqli` prepared statements method; it's safer.

```
<?php 

$DB_HOST = "xxx"; // replace with your own
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

// optional to check for empty fields
// if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['subj'])  && !empty($_POST['desc'])) {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$subject = stripslashes($_POST['subj']);
$description = stripslashes($_POST['desc']);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO organiser (`subject`, `description`) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $subject, $description);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

        else{
          echo "<h2>Success!</h2>";
        }

$stmt->close(); // Statement
$conn->close(); // MySQLi

}

?>
```

Form: (new)

```
<form action = "insert.php" method = "post">
        <label for="subj">Subject:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="subj">
        <br>
        <label for="desc">Description:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="desc">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dots around the variables and you can add some double quotes around that depending on the content of your variables :)

```
'VALUES ("'.$subject.'", "'.$description.'")';
```

Comment: or just `$sql = "INSERT INTO organiser  (subject,description)  VALUES ('$subject', '$description')";`

Comment: Very true, but then you have to explain him the difference between wrapping with simple / double quotes :)